# Optimizing the functional $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}(2xy+(y^{\prime\prime\prime})^2)dx$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Find the function $y$ with which the functional
$$J=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}(2xy+(y^{\prime\prime\prime})^2)dx$$
has extremum.

Here's what I've been suggested so far:

we use $\delta J=0$ with any $\delta y$, then
we need to write down the Euler equation $$\frac {dF}{dy}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{\prime}}\right)+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{\prime\prime}}\right)-\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{\prime\prime\prime}}\right)=0.$$
$F$ is the integerand here.
Some of the terms are $0$, so they simplify. We need to solve the differential equation. The answer should be in the form of $y=$, with constants. This is all I know so far, however I am struggling to connect the dots. I'd very much appreciate if someone could help me see the full solution.

Comment: I've added all the details.

Comment: Why the downvote, I literally provided everything I know so far.

Comment: Don't know why you have a downvote, but I'm struggling to know where you are getting stuck. Did you evaluate $\partial F/\partial y^{(k)}$ for each of the $k = 1,2,3$. What happened when you did?

Comment: @Gregory I doubt my calculations are correct, but here you go. For $k_1:2x$, $k_2:0$, $k_3:0$. How do I proceed further please? I still don't know how to solve the equation.

Comment: $$
\partial F/\partial y = 2x, \ \partial F/\partial y' = 0, \ \partial F/\partial y'' = 0, \ \partial F/\partial y''' = 2y''',
$$
Then you still need to differentiate some of those terms with $(d/dx)$. What ODE do you arrive at?

Comment: Does that mean my calculations are correct here? Does $k$ here means order of differentiation?

Comment: Maybe the syntax was confusing to you. Do you see how I calculated the values I wrote? Are you getting the same answers for those partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, I got them the same now.

Comment: @Gregory I get this differential equation: $2x-2y^{(6)}=0$. I have a feeling there's something wrong with the last term.

Comment: This is correct, just solve the equation.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I get $y(x)=c_{6}x^{5}+c_{5}x^{4}+c_{4}x^{3}+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{2}x+c_{1}+\frac{x^{7}}{5040}$. Are you sure I got the $2y^{(6)}$ part in $2x-2y^{(6)}$ correct? The answer looks a little weird.

Comment: How would you know if an answer looks weird or not if you don't have experience solving these kinds of problems? Trust your logic and math skills enough that you got to the right answer

Comment: @NinadMunshi Okay then, but what's the point of bounds of the integral from $x_0$ to $x_1$ if we don't even use them? I am confused about it as well.

Comment: The assumption with the Euler-Lagrange equation you posted is that $y(x_0) = y(x_1) = \cdots = y''(x_1) = 0$ because it is derived via integration by parts which would otherwise have those boundary terms outside of the integral.

Comment: So the point is, I should just leave the answer like this $y(x)=c_{6}x^{5}+c_{5}x^{4}+c_{4}x^{3}+c_{3}x^{2}+c_{2}x+c_{1}+\frac{x^{7}}{5040}$? I don't need to add anything?

Comment: It is correct, yay!